Convergence for a sequence using logarithmic properties?
Given the sequence $x_n=\frac{\log(3n+2)}{\log(n^2+2)}$, which has the limit $\frac{1}{2}$ when n goes to infinity, give a formal proof of the limit using the epsilon definiton.
$$| x_n - L |< \varepsilon $$
$$\left|\frac{\log(3n+2)}{\log(n^2+2)} - \frac{1}{2}\right|< \varepsilon $$
I have spend many hours attempting to prove it, using a variety of different techniques but all to no avail, and I don't have any ideas left on how to solve it, which my post history bear witness too. Everything I have attempted so far has been wrong. In particular, I struggle with finding N such that the term is less than $\varepsilon$ for all $≥$ ? Can anyone show me how to prove it? I would greatly appreciate it.

To simplify the proof we can proceed as follows
$$\left|\frac{\log(3n+2)}{\log(n^2+2)} - \frac{1}{2}\right|=\frac{\log\left(\frac{(3n+2)^2}{n^2+2}\right)}{2\log(n^2+2)} =\frac{\log\left(\frac{9n^2+12n+4}{n^2+2}\right)}{2\log(n^2+2)} \le$$
$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{9n^2+18+12n}{n^2+2}\right)}{2\log(n^2)} \le \frac{\log\left(9+\frac{12n}{n^2+2}\right)}{4\log(n)}\le \frac{\log\left(e^4\right)}{4\log(n)}=\frac1{\log n}<\varepsilon $$
then it suffices to choose $n>e^{\frac1{\varepsilon}}$.
